# Can I safely swap an incandescent in a shower recessed fixture for an LED?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, light, recessed-lighting, fire-hazard

I have an "airlock" (I believe this implies humidity reduction) recessed ceiling light in my shower. It has a 40W A15 incandescent bulb, which is now dead.

I'm looking to swap in an LED bulb; I'm aware an LED probably won't live long in such an environment, but I'm hoping the short time I actually spend showering will mitigate that.

The thing I'm really wondering is if this is safe. If I kill an LED with the damp and the heat of the recessed fixture, is there any sort of potential fire risk? Or is an incandescent so much hotter anyways that this is irrelevant?

Comment: Does the packaging for the new bulb say anything about not being installed in an enclosed fixture?

Comment: Unlikely that an LED bulb would heat the fixture as much as an incandescent but possible that a cheap imported uncertified one would *itself* be a safety issue if overheated.

Comment: You should be able to swap in a brighter (more lumen output, "60w equivalent") LED bulb into the fixture. It will provide more light while using fewer watts of electricity. Do be aware that while the LED itself produces _very minimal_ heat, the transformer built into the bulb (of a standard, Edison base replacement bulb) will produce a noticeable amount of heat. It should still be less than the equivalent "wattage" incandescent, though.